# how to fix the "the file test.doc has been modified by Sharepoint\System"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, apps-development

Issue For MM v2.0.1 the following error might occur during upgrade a document metadata:

> unable to apply the 'Test.doc' document metadata. Error message:
>   'Error code is: -2130575305, text:
>   Microsoft.[SharePoint](https://www.codecreators.ca/sharepoint-development-services/).SPException: The file Test.doc has been
>   modified by SharePoint\System...'